# php regex escaping special characters

Tags: php, regex

I wrote the following code (yes it does work) and was wondering why I don't need to escape the '<' and '>' characters inside the pattern since they are considered 'special' characters by the php manual.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

```
var_dump(preg_match('/<[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*>/', "<html>", $matches));

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(htmlentities($matches[0]));
echo "</pre>";
```

output:

```
int(1) 
string(12) "<html>"
```

Comment: Define “special” character.  All characters are special in their own way, you know. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Only the characters listed on [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) need to be escaped in PHP regex matching/replacing.

While `<` and `>` can act as [delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), it doesn't need to be escaped in the given example because you already have `/`(slash) acting as a [delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Referring to the link in question

> The **[`preg_quote()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)** function may be used to escape a string for injection into a pattern and its optional second parameter may be used to specify the delimiter to be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

`<` and `>` aren't meta characters is most contexts.

However they are used as such for:

- named capture groups `(?P<name>)`
- lookbehind assertions `(?<=...)`

So that's why [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) plays it safe and escapes them. It's arguably redundant, since escaping `(` and `?` would be sufficient. But it doesn't hurt either.