# Php Regex replace Html Closing Tags

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

Hey So I am not the best with Regex and any help would be great. I found this great snippet online and am wanting to target the closing header tags to add a fullstop then a space. Right now it targets the opening tag

```
$htmlTrash = '<div class="normal flip-below-lg"> <h3>Quick Links</h3> Do you want to monitor the seasonal changes and keep an eye on growing conditions in Central? Visit <a href="test" target="_blank">Harvest Alarms</a> weather station.</div><div class="normal flip-below-lg">Check out what we have to offer on campus on our <a href="test">Plant sales and nursery</a> page.</div>';


$string = preg_replace([
            '/<(?:br|p|div)[^>]*>/i', //replace br p div with ' '
            '/<(?:h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6)[^>]*>/i', //replace h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 with '. '
            '/\s+/u', //remove run on space - replace using the unicode flag
            '/^\s+|\s+$/u', //trim - replace using the unicode flag
        ], [
            ' ', '. ', ' ', '',
        ], $htmlTrash);

print $string;
```

The output of the above is . `Quick Links</h3> Do you want to monitor the seasonal changes and keep an eye on growing conditions in Central? Visit <a href="test" target="_blank">Harvest Alarms</a> weather station.</div> Check out what we have to offer on campus on our <a href="test">Plant sales and nursery</a> page.</div>`

I also have another reg expression later to remove all tags. But for the examples sake I just want to be able to target all closing header tags and replace it

Comment: Why are you using unicode flag to remove spaces?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you only have to escape characters [found here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) and [delimiters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317473/php-regex-escaping-special-characters). Since you're using a forward slash (`/`) as your delimiter, you'll need to escape it with a backslash (`\`). You could also change your delimiter to something other than a forward slash (such as a hash sign).

Try adding this to your `preg_replace`

`'/<(?:\/h1|\/h2|\/h3|\/h4|\/h5|\/h6)[^>]*>/i', //replace close h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 with '. '`

Edit: full code:

```
$string = preg_replace([
            '/<(?:br|p|div)[^>]*>/i', //replace br p div with ' '
            '/<(?:h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6)[^>]*>/i', //replace h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 with '. '
            '/<(?:\/h1|\/h2|\/h3|\/h4|\/h5|\/h6)[^>]*>/i', //replace close h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 with '. '
            '/\s+/u', //remove run on space - replace using the unicode flag
            '/^\s+|\s+$/u', //trim - replace using the unicode flag
        ], [
            ' ', '. ', '. ', ' ', '',
        ], $htmlTrash);
```

Note: regexes are a pain. Useful but a pain.